# Buffer in raster extract() not working when calculating proportional land cover around points

Tags: buffer, extract, raster, spatial, terra

*Why isn't the buffer function working in raster::extract when trying to caclulate proportional land cover around points?*

I'm following the steps listed here: (https://gatesdupontvignettes.com/2019/06/16/nlcd-velox-dplyr.html) to calculate proportional land cover from points.

The only difference is that I am extracting nlcd around SpatVector points. When I use raster::extract with buffer=1000 (for example) I getting a dataframe of the land cover classes for each point only (rather than all points in buffer). I was hoping to use the extract function to generate a dataframe of land cover classes for all points within an x buffer. There must be something about this raster::extract function that I'm missing but I'm at a loss for what.

### Example code

```
library(dplyr)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)

# base map 
state = ne_states(iso_a2 = "US", returnclass = "sf") %>%    # pull admin. bounds. for US
  filter(iso_3166_2 == "US-MA") %>%                         # select Massachusetts
  st_transform(crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs") # nlcd crs

# points
Lon<-c(-69.97623, -69.97674)
Lat<-c(41.90238, 41.90267)
x<-cbind(Lon,Lat)
v<-vect(x, crs="+proj=longlat")

# nlcd data
library(FedData)
nlcd = get_nlcd(        # fn for pulling NLCD data
  template = state,     # polygon template for download
  label = "4pland",     # this is just a character string label
  year = 2011,          # specify the year (2016 should be available soon)
  force.redo = F
) 

# plot
p<-project(v,crs(nlcd))
plot(nlcd)
plot(p, add=T)

# extract using raster::extract
library(raster)
nlcd # this is a SpatRaster
p # this a SpatVector
ex.1 = extract(nlcd, p, buffer=1000, df=T) # raster extract
ex.1 # returning classes around points only, not all points in buffer
```

This code is only returning the class for the point, whereas I'm looking for the classes/land cover types of all cells in the buffer around the point.

Ultimately, I am looking for the proportional land cover within a certain buffer around a number of points. I am also open to using terra::extract but haven't found a good way to include the buffer area there.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Since  `nlcd` is a SpatRaster, you are not using `raster::exract`, but rather `terra::extract`. Or, to be more precise, the `extract(SpatRaster", y="SpatVector")` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by simply buffering before extracting using `pbuff<-buffer(p, 1000)` and then using `pbuff` as the second argument in `extract()`. Note since the "terra" package has replaced the "raster" package, the workflow I present will use `terra::extract()` instead of `raster::extract()`.  Here is the full reproducible solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(terra)

# base map 
state = ne_states(iso_a2 = "US", returnclass = "sf") %>%    # pull admin. bounds. for US
  filter(iso_3166_2 == "US-MA") %>%                         # select Massachusetts
  st_transform(crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs") # nlcd crs

# points
Lon<-c(-69.97623, -69.97674)
Lat<-c(41.90238, 41.90267)
x<-cbind(Lon,Lat)
v<-vect(x, crs="+proj=longlat")

# nlcd data
library(FedData)
nlcd = get_nlcd(        # fn for pulling NLCD data
  template = state,     # polygon template for download
  label = "4pland",     # this is just a character string label
  year = 2011,          # specify the year (2016 should be available soon)
  force.redo = F
) 

# plot

p<-project(v,crs(nlcd))
plot(nlcd)
plot(p, add=T)

# extract using terra::extract
pbuff<-buffer(p, 1000)
ex.1 <- extract(nlcd, pbuff) # raster extract with terra and the polygons from the buffered points
ex.1 # now returning classes around all points in buffer
```